# Create an H2 Database from the console

Tags: h2

I would like to run H2 on my local host (Windows), and create a new database.

To do so, I have dowloaded the zip file from http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html, unzipped it, then run the `bin/h2.bat` script. I have not used the windows installer, as the machine I will be running later on does not grant me installation privileges.

The console was successfully opened on the 8082 port, but I could not create any database, failing with `Database "C:/Users/PC/test" not found [90013-198] 90013/90013`. I have tried many variations, to no avail.

The documentation states that a database should be created automatically if it does not exist, but indicates it cannot be done so from the H2 console (http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#creating_new_databases).

However, the documentation does not provide an alternate way to create a database, either by running the jar with additional parameters, or by another utility.

I feel pretty dazed right now. How do I properly create a new database in H2? I would like a normal database, persisted on disk, not an in-memory one.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that this does not work in version 198
You could download an older version (I used 196) to create the databse and then switch back to 198 to open the database.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've tried many command line arguments until I found something that worked with the latest version. Unfortunately, being an H2 beginner, I lack common knowledge about it. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to run it by using the following command line:

`java -cp h2-1.4.198.jar org.h2.tools.Server -tcp -pg -web`

I must have missed something in the documentation, sorry about this.